# "Server commited protocol violation." Error when I try to read XML from URL

Tags: c#, xml, webclient

I have problem with my application written in C#. I have a XML file on my webserver on 192.168.4.1 (works on module ESP8266). But when I try to read that XML file from that URL, it get error

> "Server committed protocol violation.. Section=ResponseStatusLine".

I read alot of thing about that, but none of these solutions worked for me.

Here is my code:

```
var url = "http://192.168.4.1/";
string xmlStr;
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
   xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(url);
}
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
```

The program stuck on line:

```
xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(url);
```

I tried to add some lines to app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <settings>
      <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true" />
    </settings>
  </system.net>

  <startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post thw whole error message of the exception? Adding the app.config should have fixed all protocol violations

Comment: Here is the error message: http://pastebin.com/FajLmas8 ...There is no path to the XML file, it is just on 192.168.4.1 like this: http://ctrlv.cz/shots/2015/03/26/Cqnv.png

Comment: Double check that you [set correctly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184658(v=vs.80).aspx) the app.config, and try to add some credential: `client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`

Comment: I edited my question, you can see full app.config now. I add wc.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; before xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(url); but the problem persists.

Comment: I solved my problem! Problem was, that I had to send a HTTP header along with data. I thought that HTTP header is sending automatically by ESP8266, but it doesn't.